# await findOneAndUpdate not waiting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a function and i need to bring some ids to populate the update on a findOneAndUpdate im using acyn and await, but the findoneandupdate runs before the others... not sure why

```
async function update(req, res) {
    const update = req.body;

    await Something1.findOne({
        'id_Something1': update.something1_id
    }).exec((err, something) => {
        if (err || !something) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error'
            })
        }
        update.something1= something._id;
    });


    await Collection.findOneAndUpdate({
        'id_something1': update.custom_id
    }, update, (err, Updated) => {
        console.log('this should show after the first find but it doesnt');
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                error: err.errmsg
            });
        } else if (!sociosUpdated) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error'
            });
        }
        res.status(200).send({
            data_updated: Updated
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: There are almost no APIs that BOTH return a promise and accept a callback at the same time.  So, chances are, you need to remove the callback you're passing to `Collection.findOneAndUpdate()` and use the awaited result instead. The same is probably true for `findOne()` too.

Comment: i tried without call and adding it as .exec() it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `async/await` and also use `asynchronous`. You can try following code:

```
async function update(req, res) {
   const update = req.body;

   try {
      const something =  await Something1.findOne({
          'id_Something1': update.something1_id
        }).exec();

      update.something1 = something && something._id;

      const Updated = await Collection.findOneAndUpdate({
        'id_something1': update.custom_id
      }).exec();

      return res.status(200).send({
        data_updated: Updated
      });
   }
   catch(err) {
       return res.status(400).send(err);
   } 
 });
```